# Select option change the text of a Textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help. I have this form:

```
<form name="user_cause" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="subject" required="required" class="form-control" onchange="showHide()">
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option value="test_1">Test_1</option>
    <option value="test_2">Test_2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <textarea id="subject_message" required="required"
            class="form-control" rows="5" disabled>
  </textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

I wish I could change the text in the disabled textarea according to the choice. how to do it with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ourArea = document.getElementById('subject_message');
var selectSubject = document.getElementById('subject');
ourArea.textContent = selectSubject.value; // omit this if you don't want initial value to be reflected in the text area
function showHide(){
    ourArea.textContent = selectSubject.value;
}
```

Comment: It works but the message I need to show is between <p></p>

exemple:
`<p id="text_1" hidden>The message of the test1</p>`

Comment: @Chidox <p> tag inside text area?

Comment: No! Only the text between the <p></p>

Comment: The question said "text in disabled textarea" .... so. You can add the <p> tag in the html, assign it an id and change "ourArea" variable to take that id instead of "subject_message" (which was for textarea).

Comment: I will explain more clairly. I want when we choose test_1 the text that will show in the disabled text area be taken from a hidden <p></p> and there is one hidden <p></p> for every choice.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what you probably want is - var idVal = selectSubject.value;
    if(idVal !== 'subject'){
     ourArea.textContent = document.getElementById(idVal).textContent;
    }

Comment: Exactly and it works! Thank you very much for your help @ishwor-timilsina

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, `$("#subject").change(function(e) { $("#subject_message").val($(this).val())});`

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery way:

```
 $("#subject").change (function() {
      $("#subject_message").text($("#subject option:selected").text();
    });
```